# Error building a stand alone plugin of GATE in JAVA

Tags: java, gate

I've being trying to build a standalone plugin using ANNIE to check the plugin creation in GATE. I have made some futile attempts in building and running the jar file in NetBeans environment.

I got the following warning:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (gate.Gate).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

And then this error:

```
gate.util.GateRuntimeException: Could not infer installed plug-ins home!
Please set it manually using the -Dgate.plugins.home option in your start-up script.
    at gate.Gate.initLocalPaths(Gate.java:320)
    at gate.Gate.init(Gate.java:167)
```

It seems the problem is embedding Gate build file into the root directory of the project?

Comment: I proposed an edit of your question, the warning and error messages are two very separate things. I bet ashingel didn't see the error message and replied for the warning :)

Comment: Thanks, Yasen. Exactly, I saw only a warning and missed error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually says in the error message what you have to do :)

I'm using Eclipse, but it shouldn't be different in NetBeans, set something like this as VM arguments, when running your code:

> -Xmx3g -Dgate.plugins.home=/home/yasen/programs/gate-8.0-build4825-ALL/plugins -Dgate.site.config=/home/yasen/.gate.xml -Dgate.home=/home/yasen/programs/gate-8.0-build4825-ALL

You'll probably need to set gate.home and gate.site.config as well.

When you call Gate.init(), GATE is trying to infer where your GATE installation is and where the plugins folder is. As you can see here:
https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch7.html#x11-1560007.1
the other option is to set an environment variable GATE_HOME, similar to JAVA_HOME, which would be used instead. If that's not set, you see this error.

Answer (score 0):

Is this error prevents from plugin building? This is just a logger error which you could ignore (or spend time and configure logger). I always ignore this error and GATE application work without any problems.